# Why does the inverse of an n-square matrix with integer entries and determinant one also have integer entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Why is $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ a group under matrix multiplication and not a monoid like General Linear $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is in fact a group, not just a monoid. It is the unit group of the ring $M_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

The reason that the inverse of a matrix in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ still has integer entries is the formula
$$ A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}\mathrm{adj}(A) $$
where $\mathrm{adj}(A)$ is the adjugate (or classical adjoint) of $A$. This matrix has integer entries, and if $A\in \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ then $\det(A)=\pm 1$, so $A^{-1}$ also has integer entries.

Comment: I thought elements of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ only had to have nonzero determinant, not necessarily a determinant equal to $\pm1$?

Comment: No, the determinant must be $\pm1$. This is a common misconception.

Comment: Yeah, I just read about the definition over commutative rings. My mistake.

Comment: @M10687 I had the misconception, too. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507710/general-linear-group-over-integers).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what is the difference between GL(n,\mathbb{Z}) and SL(n,\mathbb{Z})? I thought the difference is the determinant value.

Comment: $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is the subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ consisting of matrices with determinant equal to $1$. So the difference is the determinant value.

Comment: And general linear group may have matrices with determinant -1?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For instance $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ is in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ but not $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new to this topic.